# Prevent DataGridView from commiting a new blank row

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have an unbound DGV to which users can add rows.

By default, there's a blank row at the bottom of the grid. Let's call it row X.
When the user starts editing a cell in row X, a NEW blank row is added just below it (X+1).

[image: new blank row added when editing cell]

But after the new row is added , it's possible to delete all text in row X and leave it while its blank. The the grid is left with 2 consecutive blank rows.

[image: 2 blank rows left when leaving cell]

Using CellEndEdit event, I tried to:

1. remove row X - got an InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid because it results in a reentrant call to the SetCurrentCellAddressCore function.
2. remove row X+1 - got an InvalidOperationException: Uncommitted new row cannot be deleted.

Can't do it with CellValueChanged event either, as null to null isn't considered a change.

Is there a way to prevent this behavior / ensuring only one blank row exists at all times ?
Thanks!

Comment: Set `AllowUserToAddRows` to false and cotrol adding new rows yourself!

Answer (score 0):

The first error is telling you that a row cannot be removed if one of its cells has the current focus. So on `CellEndEdit`, set the `CurrentCell` to a cell in the row above (before trying to remove the row).

Edit: Sample code

```
public class FormClick : Form {

    DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
    DataTable table = new DataTable();

    public FormClick() {
        table.Columns.Add("A");
        table.Columns.Add("B");
        dgv.DataSource = table;
        Controls.Add(dgv);

        dgv.CellEndEdit += dgv_CellEndEdit;
    }

    void dgv_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e) {

        DataRow row = ((DataRowView) dgv.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem).Row;
        bool allEmpty = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++) {
            String s = row[i].ToString();
            if (s.Length > 0) {
                allEmpty = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (allEmpty) {
            dgv.Rows.RemoveAt(e.RowIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, it works great if I'm ending edit by pressing the Return key, but if I'm clicking on another cell, the same error is thrown ("... reentrant call to the SetCurrentCellAddressCore function."). Any ideas?

Comment: To clarify - in this case, the exception is thrown from the DGV.CurrentCell line...

Comment: @eranfu I thought I would be able to reproduce the exception, but cannot. Please modify the sample code in my edited answer to recreate the error.